# Horizontally stretched button

Tags: html, css

I've task to create button with rounded corners that will stretch horizontally to container (now containers is only div's).
It should work in IE8 and higher.

**Can you please advise is appropriate solution that I provide or there is better exist?**

My solution:

```
.button-streched {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

div.button-show-more div{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 0;
}

.button-streched .left {
    float: left;
    background-image: url(/Images/buttton-left.png);
    width: 6px;
    height: 34px;
}

.button-streched .right {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(/Images/buttton-right.png);
    width: 6px;
    height: 34px;
}

.button-streched .middle {
    background-image: url(/Images/buttton-middle.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    margin: 0px 6px;
    text-align: center;
}

.button-streched span{
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 34px;
}

div.button-streched:hover .left,
div.button-streched:hover .middle,
div.button-streched:hover .right {
    background-position: 0 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="btnButton1" class="button-streched" style="">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="middle">
            <span>Do Some Action</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Shorten version, just to demonstrate that it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/xMKhZ/

Comment: Your solution appears to work fine to me, just add `border-radius` for rounded corners? http://jsfiddle.net/xMKhZ/1/ - there is http://css3pie.com/ for IE8 support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) for rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.

Comment: Thanks, currently I'll stay on my current solution, but suggest to move on CCS3 PIE in future.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CSS with this one.

```
.button-streched {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}

div.button-show-more div{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 0;
}

.button-streched .left {
    float: left;
    background-image: url(/Images/buttton-left.png);
    width: 6px;
    height: 34px;
}

.button-streched .right {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(/Images/buttton-right.png);
    width: 6px;
    height: 34px;
}

.button-streched .middle {
    background-image: url(/Images/buttton-middle.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    margin: 0px 6px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.button-streched span{
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 34px;
}

div.button-streched:hover .left,
div.button-streched:hover .middle,
div.button-streched:hover .right {
    background-position: 0 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Then surely it ll help you. http://www.cssjuice.com/25-rounded-corners-techniques-with-css/.. This article is about 25 techniques for rounded corners..